# Silverlight 4 - Observable Collections (load on start up)

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I'm pretty new to Silverlight and C#, i've just made a little application that allows the user to add books (title, author and description), they can also search on these fields with an autocompletebox.

Now, I've only used an observable collection once and the only way I know how to use it is to use buttons (one to save and one to load the collection). However, I wish to be able to have the collection load itself when the application is started so I can then remove the button.

Can someone please advise on how I can do this? I am using MVVM as well, in case that's important.

Extra brownie points if you can also tell me how to save the collection upon exiting the application (but this is a nice to have)

Massive thanks in advance
Dom

Here is some code, sorry for not posting it before.

MainViewModel

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Xml;
using PTL.Legal.CRM.Silverlight.Common.Commanding;

namespace BookSearch1._1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private BookViewModel _selectedBook;

        #region Constructor
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(AddBook);
            SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(SaveResults);
            LoadCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(LoadResults);
            Books = new ObservableCollection<BookViewModel>();
            SelectedBook = new BookViewModel();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public void AddBook(object obj)
        {
            Books.Add(SelectedBook);
        }

        public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand LoadCommand { get; set; }

        public BookViewModel SelectedBook
        {
            get { return _selectedBook; }
            set { _selectedBook = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBook"); }
        }

        public void SaveResults(object obj)
        {
            //using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            //{
            //    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
            //        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MainSettings.xml", FileMode.Create, isf))
            //    {
            //        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            //        settings.Indent = true;

            //        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(isoStream, settings))
            //        {
            //            writer.WriteStartElement("UserSettings");

            //            foreach (string result in Books)
            //            {
            //                writer.WriteStartElement("Result");
            //                writer.WriteString(result);
            //                writer.WriteEndElement();
            //            }


            //            writer.WriteEndElement();

            //            writer.Flush();
            //        }
            //    }
            //}

            //MessageBox.Show("Settings applied.");
        }

        public void LoadResults(object obj)
        {
            //using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            //{
            //    var storStream =
            //        new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MainSettings.xml", FileMode.Open, isf));

            //    var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
            //                                {
            //                                    IgnoreWhitespace = true,
            //                                    IgnoreComments = true,
            //                                    CheckCharacters = true
            //                                };

            //    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(storStream, xmlReaderSettings);

            //    while (xmlReader.Read())
            //    {
            //        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
            //            "Result" == xmlReader.LocalName)
            //        {
            //            Books.Add(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
            //        }
            //    }

            //    xmlReader.Close();
            //}
        }

        #endregion

        public AutoCompleteFilterPredicate<object> CustomFilter 
        { 
            get 
            {
                return new AutoCompleteFilterPredicate<object>(SearchBooks);
            }
        }


        bool SearchBooks(string search, object value)
        {
            // Cast the value to an Employee.
            var books = value as BookViewModel;
            if (books != null)
            {
                // Look for a match in the first and last names.
                if (SelectedBook.Title.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || SelectedBook.Author.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || SelectedBook.Description.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                    return true;

            }
            // If no match, return false.
            return false;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<BookViewModel> Books { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: please post some code about your logic. thanks

Comment: i've posted the MainViewModel, hope this helps, thanks

Comment: check Daok's and dev.bv's answer. that's the right direction. also, I should refactor your code, but that belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to load the collection (Looks like the method is LoadResults) in the ViewModel constructor. So, somewhat like this:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(AddBook);
    SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(SaveResults);
    LoadCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(LoadResults);
    Books = new ObservableCollection<BookViewModel>();
    SelectedBook = new BookViewModel();

    LoadResults();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use MVVM I suggest that the `View Model` load the Collection to the `Model`. Once this is done, the ObservableCollection will raise a change and if you have bind the collection to the `View` you'll see the data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. 

I might be reading your reply wrong or not understanding. The collection is already bound to the view but at present the user has to click a button to get the collection to load into a listbox but i wish the collection to load when the application is started.

again, sorry if i've just misunderstood your reply

Answer (score 0):

Look in a file named App.xaml.  There is an event in there named Application_Startup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks alot, i wasn't sure where to find this.

I do have another noob issue as a result of this. I have a ref to the collection called Books (which is in the MainViewModel), it tells me that the name Books does not exist in the current context.

My understanding of this is that the MainViewModel needs to be referenced, which i think i would need have the class inherited but the App class already inherits from Application, and as far as i know you can only inherit from one class??

AS i say, prob a real noob issue, thanks for your help

Comment: Do you really need to load the data when the app first starts up?  Can you not load it in the constructor of the MainViewModel?  Does the MainViewModel remain in memory for the life of the application?  We need a bit more info regarding your app.

Comment: Thanks again, good question, i just need it to load the collection when the application starts, i wasn't aware there was another way to do this (again, noob lol)

I've posted the MainViewModel for you to look at :o)

Comment: I think the other suggestions on this thread are pointing you in the right direction i.e. load the data in the constructor of the View Model.  You can easily call a service and retrieve results in the Application_Startup event (as mentioned above), however you will then need to store the data somewhere and at this stage you probably won't have any ViewModels loaded.  For this reason I would probably agree with the other answers provided here.